# Accessing CustomEditor Inspector values from another scene

Tags: c#, editor, unity-game-engine, inspector

So I'm using a CustomEditor setup to make a Spawn Point manager.  I've got it setup to add spawn points in a scene (let's call it Room 1), no problems there.  What I need to do next is load up a different scene (Room 2) and make a door interact reference a spawn point from Room 1.  I have all parts of the equation setup except for how to get a list of spawn points in Room 1 while I'm editing the Room 2 scene.

Is there a way to call up a query of the values setup in an object in Room 1 scene while I'm editing Room 2 scene?  Keep in mind this is in the editor/inspector, not while the application is running, so I don't think player prefs and DontDestroyOnLoad will help here.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to call up a query of the values setup in an object in
>   Room 1 scene while I'm editing Room 2 scene?

No, you can't. The editor let you open one scene at the time. You can consider different scenes as different worlds. 
You can add the content of a scene to the current opened scene, using [EditorApplication.OpenSceneAdditive](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorApplication.OpenSceneAdditive.html). Btw this isn't useful for your case, since the object of the scene added are copied inside the opened one.

If you need to share objects between scenes you have 2 ways to do that:

1. Use a [Prefab](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Prefabs.html) for your SpawnPoint Manager, if your Component is attached to a GameObject.
2. If you don't want/can use a GameObject to store your SpawnPoint Manager (I don't think this is the case), you may consider using [AssetDatabase](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html). Basically you can store inside it every serializable class derived from [ScriptableObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html).

What I would do in your case is, more or less, the following:

- Create an empty `GameObject` with attached a [Component](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component.html) called `SpawnPointManager`.
- Create a `Prefab` from the created `GameObject`.
- Put in all scenes a `Prefab instance` of your manager.
- Eventually define a custom [Editor](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Editor.html) for modify your `SpawnPointManager` `Component` from a custom inspector

Since all your `Prefab instances` are linked to the same `Prefab`, even if they are in different scenes, basically the share the same object (accessible from the inspector). So if you modify the `prefab` it self (or an instance of it and apply the modification back to the linked prefab), **all your prefab instances (even in the different scenes) will see the modifications and will update accordingly to the linked prefab**.

Comment: A prefab is basically what I had already done.  Unfortunately there wasn't a way to distinguish between scenes if I kept copying the changes into the root prefab.  If Room 1 had 4 spawn points and Room 2 had 3, then the prefab can't really be updated.  In order to access info across scenes, the prefab needed to know everything.  But in order for the prefab to know everything, it would have to hold spawn points that some scenes wouldn't want.

Comment: What I ended up doing is just using an enum for a list of possible names to choose from and allowed the user to set that name when making the spawn point.  You can access that same list with the load triggers.  It's not as dynamic as I'd like, requiring an update to the enum if you need a new name, but it's still better than hand typing names in (too much human error.)